# c# Web Content Filter

Tags: c#, .net, web

Can anyone point me to any GOOD open source .NET parental web content filters? I would like to gain an understanding of how I can filter/block web traffic based on Url and/or keyword.

I've looked on google but can't seem to find any developed c#

Answer (score 1):

Usually the content filters use black and white listing. Keywords are pretty unreliable, and unless implemented properly, you will be blocking a lot of sites of distinguished members of society and organizations where the words magna cum laude happen to reside.

There were some cool articles credit to Jeff where he was discussing the things about Bayesian Filters.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/09/some-plans-for-spam.html

I think that this is a good start.